# Select element - Post method - return of value / Php

Tags: php, database

I'm having a hard time to fix and how can make my codes work well.

My textbox echo correctly while my dropdown box is not.

Can anyone help me and also clean my codes?

I wanna know how did you do it and can u please explain it to me.

Thank you so much.

**index.php**

```
<?php include 'test.php' ?>

<form method="post" action="index.php">
Textbox:    <input type="text" name="txt1" value="<?php echo $txt1;?>">
Dropdown:   <select name="drpdown1" value="<?php echo $drpdown1;?>">
                <option></option>
                <option value="1">Mark</option>
                <option value="2">Extreme</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="btn1">
</form>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
$txt1 = "";
$drpdown1 = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $txt1 = $_POST["txt1"];
    $drpdown1 = $_POST["drpdown1"];
}   
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not echoing the value of `$drpdown1` correctly:

```
// this is wrong for a select:
<select name="drpdown1" value="<?php echo $drpdown1;?>">
  // etc.
```

If you want to select automatically the previously selected value, you need to add the `selected` attribute:

```
<select name="drpdown1">
  <option value="1" <?php if ($drpdown1 === '1') { echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>Mark</option>
  <option value="2" <?php if ($drpdown1 === '2') { echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>Extreme</option>
  // etc.
```

Comment: i just want, what was chosen on the drop down will be return.

Comment: @NiCeMaRK Ummmmm, yes, that is exactly what the above code does... Have you tried it?

Comment: you just did solved my problem! thanks much! wait, but if ever i want it blank when data were load before the user chose on the dropdown box. i will just put <option></option> right?

Comment: @NiCeMaRK Yes; the first option will be selected if none of the others is selected.

Comment: when it comes on inserting it to the database. $drpdown1 will be the one to be inserted and to be returned into, right?

Comment: @joreon , i have another problem. i want my test.php to be include only after clicking the submit button. how should i do that? a hidden type element and another condition?

Comment: hey mate. one more thing. how am i going to catch the value from my database and will echo it on my dropdown?

Comment: @NiCeMaRK That's something completely different so you should probably ask a new question posting the relevant database code.

Comment: sir, can u help me here with my other question, please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41742250/return-value-of-select-element-from-database-php?noredirect=1#comment70679417_41742250

Answer (score 0):

you have to know more about the dropdown box because you can not put the value inside the

```
 <select value="<?php echo $drpdown1;?>">
```

you have to compare the value inside the option directly. example

```
<select name="drpdown1">
    <?php
        if($drpdown1 == ""){
    ?>
             <option selected></option>
             <option value="1">Mark</option>
             <option value="2">Extreme</option>
    <?php
        }else if($drpdown1 == "1"){
    ?>
             <option></option>
             <option value="1" selected>Mark</option>
             <option value="2">Extreme</option>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</select>
```